# How to set printing parameter on browser

Tags: google-chrome-extension, browser, printing, cross-browser, browser-addons

The "set printing parameter" means be able to setting margin, paper size, font size, etc.
My project require to set default print setting based on different report user want to print. And I find @page in css wouldn't do the job. It still need to choose correct paper size.

I'm finding a way to do this, and I'm thinking about something like ActiveX.

It looks like only IE supports ActiveX. And I would like to know modern browser could do this kind of job by add-ons.

I'm looking for a way to do it by code, not by clicking in print dialog or browser settings.